# Uninstalled MS Store, won't reinstall now(In an attempt to fix hanging and crashing apps)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store

as I was following the guide here, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/fix-hanging-or-crashing-apps/5532c189-f316-4c20-9f63-34d8b51215f1, this person (the first reply I saw) dictates I uninstall and reinstall MS Store. I used the following command:

```
Get-AppXPackage *WindowsStore* -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

This command doesn't work, and gives lots of reds.

Does anyone have an idea of what to do? Other than of course resetting my Laptop, no way.

Comment: Can you get Microsoft Store this way ?  https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/store/apps/windows

Comment: @John nope doesnt work

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair install from the Microsoft Media Creation link.   That will likely work.